# Static Assert for NVCC and Compiler Bug

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Whats the best way to have a static assert for the NVCC compiler inside a struct which is used for compile time settings:

The following works mostly but sometimes NVCC produces bullshit error messages, and does not compile even if it should!

```
template<int A, int B>
struct Settings{

   static const int a = A;
   static const int b = B;
   STATIC_ASSERT(a  == 15);
}
typedef Settings<15,5> set1; // Comment this out and it works....

template<int A, int B>
struct Settings2{

   static const int a = A;
   static const int b = B;
   STATIC_ASSERT(a % b == 0);
}
typedef Settings<10,5> set2;
```

The static assert does not work, I dont know but there is a CUDA Compiler BUG which tells me when I compile it throws the  STATIC_ASSERT(a  == 15); even if IT should COMPILE because the code above is correct, if I comment (A) out then it suddenly works,
I use the STATIC_ASSERT from Thrust which is basically taken from Boost:

```
    #define JOIN( X, Y ) DO_JOIN( X, Y )
#define DO_JOIN( X, Y ) DO_JOIN2(X,Y)
#define DO_JOIN2( X, Y ) X##Y

namespace staticassert {

   // HP aCC cannot deal with missing names for template value parameters
   template <bool x> struct STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE;

   template <> struct STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<true> { enum { value = 1 }; };

   // HP aCC cannot deal with missing names for template value parameters
   template<int x> struct static_assert_test{};

};

// XXX nvcc 2.3 can't handle STATIC_ASSERT

#if defined(__CUDACC__) && (CUDA_VERSION > 100)
#error your version number of cuda is not 2 digits!
#endif

#if defined(__CUDACC__) /* && (CUDA_VERSION < 30)*/


#define STATIC_ASSERT( B ) typedef staticassert::static_assert_test<sizeof(staticassert::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE< (bool)( (B) ) >) > JOIN(thrust_static_assert_typedef_, __LINE__)
#define STATIC_ASSERT2(B,COMMENT) STATIC_ASSERT(B)


#else
#define STATIC_ASSERT2(B,COMMENT) \
   typedef staticassert::static_assert_test< \
      sizeof(staticassert::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE< (bool)( (B) ) >)>\
         JOIN(thrust_static_assert_typedef_, JOIN(__LINE__, COMMENT ))

#define STATIC_ASSERT( B ) \
   typedef staticassert::static_assert_test<sizeof(staticassert::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE< (bool)( (B) ) >) > JOIN(thrust_static_assert_typedef_, __LINE__)

#endif // NVCC 2.3
```

Did anybody experience the same problem?

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: I am using boost's static assert in my CUDA sources (using nvcc 3.2). When the assert fails, the error message is not so nice, but I didn't encounter an assert failing when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the missing semicolons after each `struct` definition, your code compiles with no warnings or errors for me.  System details:

```
harrism$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2010 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Nov_11_15:26:50_PST_2010
Cuda compilation tools, release 3.2, V0.2.1221

harrism$ g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```